# Is the Earth a proper or common noun?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

I guess the website got this wrong. It says that the Earth is a common noun. In my view it should be a proper noun. Please see the [screenshot](https://postimg.cc/JsBCRjfk).

[image]

> 13. **The earth moves round the sun.**
>
> • Earth is a common noun
>   • Earth is an abstract noun
>   • Earth is a proper noun

Comment: Look it up in a dictionary before asking others for help, please.

Comment: I couldn't make it up

Comment: Also, it's spelled 'common' not 'comman'.

Comment: @DanBron Dictionary can't help in this case.

Comment: @user357374 See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Duplicate of [What is the correct capitalization of the words 'earth' and 'moon'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152683/what-is-the-correct-capitalization-of-the-words-earth-and-moon/152686#152686)////// Duplicate of [When is it correct to capitalise 'earth'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2286/when-is-it-correct-to-capitalise-earth)

Comment: The question needs tightening; 'E/earth' and 'the E/earth' are different entities.

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking whether "earth" in “The earth moves [a]round the sun” is a common or proper noun. If the authors had capitalized it, then technically, the answer would have been "proper noun".

Proper nouns do not normally take a determiner. For example,

- *Let's go to **Paris*** on ***Thursday***.
- *I left **Washington** last night.*
- *Did you visit **Lake Como** in **July**?*
- *Her favourite movie is*, *When **Harry** Met **Sally***.

BUT there are exceptions

- *Have you ever seen* ***the*** *Amazon River*?
- *I saw special gift subscriptions on* ***The*** New York Times.

However, these proper nouns are always capitalised whereas *[**earth**](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/earth)* is also a common noun and a synonym of *soil*, *land*, *dirt*, *ground*, *terrain* etc.

Comment: *River* in "the Amazon river" is not capitalized.

Comment: @Kris I always check these things before posting, and on Wikipedia it is capitalised https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_River  as  is Apurímac River, Mantaro River , Ucayali River, Solimões River ... see also Britannica Encyclopedia: [The Amazon River is located in the northern portion of South America, flowing from west to east.](https://www.britannica.com/place/Amazon-River)

Comment: Context! "Four centuries after the European discovery of the Amazon river, the total cultivated area ...." [*ibid*].

Comment: and for good measure [Learn all there is to know about this incredible ecosystem and make your **Amazon River** visit in South America all the more rewarding.](https://www.chimuadventures.com/blog/2016/07/amazon-river/)

Comment: We are into the English language for now. And backdoor promotions are just wrong.

Comment: BUT there are exceptions

_Have you ever seen the Amazon?_

Comment: Rainforest or river? @EdwinAshworth

Comment: Hey, I'm supporting you here. Try the Limpopo. There are plenty of proper nouns that take the definite article (sometimes also capitalised). One is the [Great Saint Bernard Pass {Britannica}](https://www.britannica.com/place/Great-Saint-Bernard-Pass). But why answer and close-vote for duplicity?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth sorry, seemed you were supporting Kris's comment.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the question is not off topic, it's a duplicate and I'd prefer to see it closed as such. However, so far it's a tie: 2 (dupe) 2 (off topic). Not sure what to do, I might retract the close vote and see how it moves on from there.

Comment: The only proper choice is which dupe to cite.

Comment: Some flexibility is permissible, originally this was a comment and then I threw caution to the wind and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it (although to me it is somewhat ambiguous so apologies if I have misunderstood) the answer provided by @Mari-LouA implies that if the word “earth” is not capitalized it is not a proper noun, even where it refers to the planet, as in the King James Bible (Math 24:35):

> Heaven and earth shall pass away…

and in many other examples in answers to the [SE question on the spelling of earth/Earth](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/510241/why-is-earth-often-spelt-with-a-lowercase-e-even-when-referring-to-the-planet/513035#513035) both with and without the definite article.

If so, I would disagree. It seems to me to come down to the distinction between what is a ‘proper noun’ and what are the consequences of a word being a proper noun. Let us look at a *standard* definition, e.g. from SE ELU tag.

> A proper noun or proper name is a **capitalized** noun **representing a unique entity** as opposed to a common noun, which represents a class of entities or non-unique instances of that class.

And [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/proper_noun) has a similar definition in which both the description and the orthography are part of the definition.

On this basis earth can be neither a proper noun (not capitalized) nor a common noun (represents a unique entity).

*This seems to me neither proper logic nor common sense.*

My answer (supported by common sense and the rather long abstract from the Wikipedia article below) is:

> **The earth** (and sun and moon) when used to refer to the planet in common writing (rather than technical astronomical writing where they lack a determiner and are capitalized) **is a proper noun** because it refers to a unique entity. The fact that it is not capitalized is exceptional but merely an irregularity in language and orthography.

Is this important linguistically? I may be wrong, but I am unaware of any other reason to classify nouns as proper or common other than orthography. If I am correct (he ducks) then this is a useful help for orthography but not an infallible rule. This is English. Who is surprised?

**Abstract from [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun)** (with my emphasis)

> *A proper noun is a noun that identifies a single entity* and is used to refer to that entity, such as London, Jupiter, Sarah, or Microsoft, as distinguished from a common noun, which is a noun that refers to a class of entities …*The detailed definition of the term is problematic and, to an extent, governed by convention.*
>
> …A distinction is normally made in current linguistics between proper nouns and proper names. By this strict distinction, because the term noun is used for a class of single words (tree, beauty), only single-word proper names are proper nouns: Peter and Africa are both proper names and proper nouns; but Peter the Great and South Africa, while they are proper names, are not proper nouns.
>
> …In English and many other languages, proper names and words derived from them are *associated with capitalization; but the details are complex*, and vary from language to language.

**Coda**

I suppose I should propose a change in the tag, assuming I have enough rep to do so:

> A proper noun or proper name is a noun **representing a unique entity** as opposed to a common noun, which represents a class of entities or non-unique instances of that class. Proper nouns are generally **capitalized** in English, but there are a few (e.g. earth) which are not.

Comment: I'm afraid you're confusing a noun with a noun phrase. When 'the earth' or 'the Earth' refers to planet Earth, it's not the noun 'earth' or 'Earth' but the noun phrase 'the earth' or 'the Earth' that "refers to a unique entity". Any NP with a common noun as its head and a definite determiner (e.g., _the_) can refer to a unique entity: _the book_, _the car_, _the town_, _the planet_, etc.

Comment: @JK2  -— OK, I chose the wrong biblical quotation. How about “ Heaven and earth shall pass away”  Math 24:35. Noun phrase?

Comment: @JK2 The question contains this error. / Some modern theories say that 'the Earth' say is better classed as a determiner phrase. I wonder if we're heading for proper determiners? Proper zero determiners?

Comment: @David The Bible was originally written by whoever was not even aware of the concept of a planet as we know it, so any translation of the Bible into English cannot possibly have meant "earth" as planet Earth. Indeed, 'earth' in your sentence I think means the dry land as opposed to the waters/seas. And 'earth' as the dry land has always been a common non-count noun, which can always be used without any determiner.

Comment: @JK2 — I think your comments relate to the origin of the current usage, discussed in the question I cited. However even that usage has the clear sense of referring to a unique entity, and subsequent and current usage (e.g. "move heaven and earth") has a mental association with the planet. I also do not accept your previous argument about noun phrases (whatever they are) because "the planet" is not the same as "the earth": there are many planets but only one called Earth. I'll leave it there, but suggest you might want to frame your own answer, opposing mine. Then people can judge.

Comment: @David Heaven an earth provides no evidence whatsoever, because coordinate NP's freely occur as bare NPs. Your answer is factually incorrect in any case, because it would exclude "Smiths" in "the Smiths". Don't use dictionaries for grammar advice. It's not what tgey're designed for.